# How much of the decay energy is left when the electron escapes to large distances?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, weak-interaction, orbitals

During a neutron decay, there is distribution of KE of electron. When KE given to electron is $0.782~\mathrm{MeV}$ (max) , it escapes from proton field. A lot of this KE is used for Potential Energy. 
Some is left with electron. Can someone tell me?

Edit: $13.6~\mathrm{eV}$ is needed to escape when electron is $52.9pm$ away from nucleus. 
During nuclear reaction, electron escapes from proton. Size of proton is $0.877fm$. This will require much more energy for electron to escape.

Comment: Neutron decay is a three body problem. Your question does not make sense.

Comment: @JonCuster I know three particles involved, proton, electron and anti-neutrino. What is not making sense?

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you! John Rennie told me it escapes proton field. Can you answer my edit please?

Comment: @ Anubhav  There are four possible values of energy of  electrons coming out from beta /neutron decay, depending on the mechanism....Fermi, Gamow-Teller, Mixed  and another GT transition(larger half life), i wonder why you are only quoting the 'Mixed" one-

Comment: So presumably the questions is "How much of the maximum decay energy is left when the electron escapes to large distances?" But you didn't actually *ask* that question. Clarity is the first virtue in technical writing, and it is rather lacking here.

Comment: @dmckee : Thank you!!!! Clarity and English are two among things I was not born with.

Comment: If an electron has to escape from a proton's field it needs about 13.6 eV only and that is available from 0.782 MeV (max. energy).....so <A lot of this KE is used for Potential Energy> this statement  in the question is not very clear to me.

Comment: @drvrm I am still working on your first comment. I am searching for what you said in that comment. So, I cannot reply or make any advancement now. For your last comment I edited question.

Comment: < Size of proton is 0.877fm. This will require much more energy for electron to escape.> @ Anubhav Goel.. we are discussing neutron decay and proton is part of the product of the decay scheme so the classical distances and potential energy may land us in overestimating the loss /slowing down .. the coulomb factor was estimated by Fermi and some graphical data on coulomb energy is available...i  will be providing you reference related to  my comments shortly.

Comment: <http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/ch374/ch418518/Chapter%208%20Beta%20Decay-rev.pdf> @Anubhav Goel ,  pl. see the reference related to my comments.

Comment: @drvrm Page Not Found

We're sorry, but we can't find the Web page you requested.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel This might work http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/ch374/ch418518/Chapter%208%20Beta%20Decay-rev.pdf

Comment: @AnubhavGoel I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#Energy_release) would be trustworthy source

Comment: @VishnuJK Do you think I had not read it? I read it before posting question.

Comment: @Anubhav ... i think they have included the electron in  beta decay as their Q value is taken as difference of the masses of neutral atoms having atomic number z and z+1. so we not jump to conclusions about trustworthiness of the reference.i think the problem is that the experimental studies on beta decay energies do not take the coulomb term  to have a very  dominant role as far as energy profile is concerned...no doubt one can investigate further...

Comment: @drvrm Oh! I understood it. It was correct, sorry for inconvenience to you and Vishnu both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$0.782~\text{MeV} = (\text{neutron mass}) - (\text{isolated proton mass}) - (\text{isolated electron mass}) - (\text{isolated neutrino mass})$$
Note that all the particles are isolated here. That means that, immediately after the neutron decay, the proton, electron, and neutrino total kinetic energy is slightly *more* than $0.782~\text{MeV}$. Then, after they travel far away from each other (overcoming their electrical attraction), *now* the total kinetic energy of the three particles is exactly $0.782~\text{MeV}$.

A separate question is how the $0.782~\text{MeV}$ is distributed among the three particles. The answer involves some math; you should ask it as a separate question if you're interested.

Comment: Isolated means their rest mass, is it fine? So, 0.782 should be free energy available from decay and not energy available after decay

Comment: "Isolated" is not a technical jargon term. It means what it means in everyday speech: "Far away from any other particle". For example, an electron which is 1 femtometer from a proton is obviously not "isolated". Rest mass is *by definition* the mass of an *isolated* particle at rest.

Comment: Consider my imagination. There was big sphere called neutron. Then a scientist with his equipment took out a big scoop called proton(with mass equal to that of isolated proton), then small scoops of electron and neutrino(again isolated mass). Then , he found some energy left. He measured it to be 0.782MeV. Then, he gave that energy to three as Kinetic Energy. While they were moving away they lost some to Potential Energy, I am asking how much?

Comment: Can you amend above story to explain, did you mean mass of proton changed when it was near and far. Do you mean an isolated proton has more mass than one near electron? I thought mass is invariant.

Comment: Well , I know mass of proton reduces in nucleus as for binding energy. But, that is not needed here.

Comment: (mass of hydrogen atom) < (isolated proton mass) + (isolated electron mass), because of binding energy. So, does the proton weigh less because the electron is near? Or does the electron weigh less because the proton is near? Or neither or both? I don't know! Those questions are pointless, they have no answer. Rest mass is by definition the energy of an *isolated* particle at rest. When a particle is not isolated, its "mass right now" is an obscure notion, and might even be altogether meaningless (as far as I know).

Comment: I am beginning to understand you. I will write a new story.

Comment: There was big sphere called neutron. Then a scientist with his equipment took out a big scoop called proton(with mass less than isolated proton), then small scoops of electron and neutrino(again less). Then , he found some energy left. He measured it to be greater than 0.782MeV. Let 1.4 MeV. Then, he gave that energy to three as Kinetic Energy. While they were moving away they lost some to Potential Energy which increased there mass slightly, like giving binding energy back to mass. Then all three were isolated and had left with 0.782MeV KE.

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: Your story is full of errors. A proton is not a scoop inside a neutron - it doesn't exist until the decay happens. "Mass" of a particle always means "isolated mass" by definition: You should not talk about the mass of a non-isolated particle. Etc. If you want a correct story, I already wrote it for you: "Immediately after the neutron decay, the proton, electron, and neutrino total kinetic energy is slightly more than 0.782MeV. Then, after they travel far away from each other (overcoming their electrical attraction), now the total kinetic energy of the three particles is exactly 0.782MeV."